# A different definition of partial ordering

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, relations

So far from what I've found on the internet, every definition of a non-strict partially ordered set uses these axioms:

$1.$ reflexivity

$2.$ antisymmetry

$3.$ transitivity

But in a textbook from my university, there is another definition which uses these axioms:

$1.$ asymmetry

$2.$ transitivity

The textbook also states that the strict order is a partial order that is trichotomous.

How do these two definitions correlate? Why are they not equal (since the first definition requires reflexivity and the second one forbids it by asymmetry)? What is the motivation behind the second definition?

edit: I apologize for inconvinience. The book doesn't really uses terms *non-strict* and *strict*, but rather *partial order* and *order*. It's not written in English and I thought there were only two widely used types of orders, namely a *strict order* and a *non-strict order*. So perhaps I only confused terminology.

Comment: Think about the difference between "$\le$" and "$<$" ...

Comment: Sure, but both above definitions are defining "$\leq$".

Comment: @Gogis No, the second one does not capture $\le$.  $\le$ is not asymmetric.

Comment: I believe the second one is defining "$<$." Many texts use "partially ordered set" to refer to the *strict* inequality. Note that they're "morally" equivalent, since we can define $\le$ from $<$ and vice versa.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, but the book then defines *strict* inequality on its own by adding trichotomy to the two axioms. Therefore it really is a definition of a non-strict inequality.

Comment: Note the entry in Wikipedia (compare info about posets, with this entry about "strict" posets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders.  It correlates with the answers given in the comments.  In the first case, we have $x \leq x$ (true); in the second case, we have $x\lt x?$ (clearly false.) In the second case, we have Irreflexivity, antisymmetry, and transitivity.

Comment: @Noah  In no way can $\lt$ represent a poset.  A poset must be reflexive, which we get with $\leq$.

Comment: Gogis:  Note that "anti-symmetry" and "asymmetry" are not diametrically opposed.  This is why folks have modeled the difference between the first and second by using the examples, in the first: $\leq$ relation, vs. $lt$ relation.  In the first case, we indeed do have reflexivity, in the second case, there does not exist an $x$ in the set over which the relation is defined, such that $x\lt x$ hence, irreflexive.

Comment: @amWhy Some texts define posets via $<$, rather than $\le$. It depends on the author. Incidentally, Gogis, your use of "strict" does not match the one I've seen; what you call "strict" is, I think, more commonly called "**total**" (or "linear"). The meaning of "strict" in this context that I've seen is to distinguish between "$<$" and "$\le$."

Comment: @Noah A poset (partially ordered set) is defined by the following properties: reflexivity, antisymmetry, transiivity.  $\lt$ fails reflexivity.

Comment: @amWhy As I said, **that depends on the author**. Some texts define posets differently - a la "$<$," rather than "$\le$." This kind of ambiguity is unfortunately common in mathematics. (Also, I **do** know what "poset" stands for ...)

Comment: @NoahSchweber As I see it, trichotomy is basically the difference between 'partial' and 'total', not between 'non-strict' and 'strict' (see second half of my Answer)... is the OP's textbook wrong?  I think it is!

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, where did I say otherwise? Note that in my original comment I use "strict" to refer to the $</\le$ distinction. (The OP's second source, in my opinion, *is* wrong to use "strict" this way, but it is perhaps used that way in other (older?) sources, I can't say for sure.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, so possibly another interesting bit of 'history of mathematics terminology' .. thanks!

Comment: Ok, maybe I really screwed up by confusing terminology. The book isn't in English and I thought there were only two known "orders," i.e. *strict* and *non-strict.* I do not know what should I do now. Is it ok to delete the question?
edit: the book defines a *partial order* and then a *order*

Comment: @Gogis  Keep the question. You've accepted an upvoted answer, and do not seem to have received any downvotes, nor any close votes.  You've done fine. +1

Comment: I edited the question. Does it make any more sense now?

Comment: Also, I'm very sorry for the trouble. My confusion could be casued simply by my lack of knowledge about the terminology.

Comment: Gogis:  No need to apologizie. really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relation is asymmetric if and only if it is anti-symmetric and irreflexive.

So, the second definition can be rewritten as:

1. Irreflexive
2. Anti-symmetric
3. Transitive

And now the relation between the two definitions is a little more clear:  they are both transitive and anti-symmetric, but the strict one is irreflexive, and the non-strict one is reflexive.

Note that a 'non-strict' partial order is not the same as a relation that is anti-symmetric, transitive, but not strict, for it could be anti-symmetric, transitive, but neither reflexive nor irreflexive ... I also wish there was a term for relations that are anti-symmetric and transitive (and I believe 'order' fits the bill just right) ... but I get the impression that we don't consider such 'in-between orders' because they are mathematically not that interesting ... see also:

[Orders, Partial Orders, Strict Partial Orders, Total Orders, Strict Total Orders, and Strict Orders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210560/orders-partial-orders-strict-partial-orders-total-orders-strict-total-orders)

As far as the connection with trichotomy goes: There I do not understand the textbook. Trichotomy for any relation $R$ is that for any two objects $x$ and $y$: $xRy$ or $yRx$ or $x=y$. Put differently: if $x \not = y$, then either $xRy$ or $yRx$, which is also known as a 'connex' relationship: every two different elements are 'connected'. Thus, for example, $\subseteq$ is not connex, as $\{ 1 \}$ and $\{ 2 \}$ do not stand in the $\subseteq$ relation in any way, but $\le$ is connex ... which is also why we call it a 'total' order (a relation is 'total' when for any $x$ and $y$, either $xRy$ or $yRx$ ... note that connex/trichotomy plus reflexive implies total).

But $\le$ is clearly not strict. That is, $\le$ is a partial order that is connex (i.e for which trichotomy holds), but it is not a strict partial order.

So, frankly, I disagree with the book on that one: the difference between 'non-strict' and 'strict' is not 'connex' or trichotomy (*that* is the difference between partial and total). Rather, the difference between 'strict' and 'non-strict' is the difference between reflexive and irreflexive.

Comment: Please address the asker's concern about the property of trichotomy holding in the second definition. Rather, I will.  Trichotomy holds, because, e.g., the relation $\lt$, on the set of real numbers, it is true that $\forall a, b(a\lt b\lor  a= b \lor b\lt a).$

Comment: @amWhy Will do!

Comment: Bram28  Thanks! (for the edits).${}{}{}{}$  My comment on your last paragraph is no longer relevant; you've already edited it and updated the post, so all is good.+

Comment: @amWhy Oh, ok, phew!  ... but so you agree that the OP's book is wrong in saying that a strict order is a partial order that is trichotomous? I.e that trichotomy has nothing to do with partial vs strict?

Comment: Indeed I do, Bram28.

Comment: @amWhy Phew again! It always makes me nervous when claiming some book is wrong .... :)

Comment: You done good, here, Bram28!  :)

Comment: Yes, the *strict partial order* and the *strict linear order* (from the question you linked in your answer) fit the *partial order* and the *order* definitions from the book. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks, I appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Gogis Great, glad I was able to help! :)