# Total weak order vs total order

Tags: order-theory

I want to know the difference between "total weak order" and "[total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)".
Total order is clear for me, but not that of "total weak order". Is it equivalent to "partial ordering"?

Thanks!

Comment: in a weak ordering, some elements may be tied with each other

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Can I get an example pls?

Comment: consider points of $\mathbb R^2$ ordered by distance from $(0,0)$

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "total weak order". Do you have an example of its usage? One concept I have heard of is that of a [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings), which is the complement of a [total preorder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Total_preorders). (I hope I'm not just adding to your confusion!)

Comment: For any fixed set $X$, let $S$ be the power set of $X$ (set of all subsets of $X$). The inclusion ordering (i.e. "subset of") is a partial ordering on $S$, and the cardinality ordering $x R y $ iff $|x| <= |y|$, is a weak total ordering on $S$.

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley I found the term "total weak order" when I read the following paper: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/int.20329

Comment: The abstract of that paper suggests that the context is measurement theory. Krantz et al., *Foundations of Measurement, vol. I: Additive and Polynomial Representations* (1971, repr. Dover 2007), p.14, define a "weak order" as a total preorder (i.e. in their usage, "total" is implicit). It looks increasingly likely that the other commenters are right, and a total preorder is what is meant, but it would be good to have a reference for this.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing these things as though the adjectives compose is [dangerous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4775436/1161064), but:

- A (strict or non-strict) weak ordering is a (strict or non-strict, respectively) total ordering of equivalence classes, where unequal elements might be in the same equivalence class, e.g. ordering people by age, where all people of the same age form an equivalence class. Totality of the ordering of equivalence classes means, elements of any two distinct equivalence classes are comparable, i.e. *x*R*y* ∨ *y*R*x*.
- Strictness would mean that elements of every equivalence class are all incomparable with one another (¬*x*R*y* ∧ ¬*y*R*x*), and non-strictness would mean they're all comparable (*x*R*y* ∧ *y*R*x*).
- As far as I can tell, totality is the property that every pair of
  unequal items is related, i.e. *x*≠*y* ⇒ *x*R*y* ∨ *y*R*x* (Wikipedia
  [appears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation) to be a little bit confused about the concept, but I
  think what it says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_relation) is right).

So making a weak ordering total means that unequal elements of every equivalence class are somehow related.  They have to be related in both directions (*x*R*y* ∧ *y*R*x*) or it wouldn't be an equivalence class, so I think that implies non-strictness and reflexivity. But (unfortunately) you never have to say “non-strict,” so I think a “total weak order” has to be what most people mean by a “weak order.”