# Different types of orders: Partial Order, Weak order, Strict partial Order, Weak partial order, Strict weak order, and Equivalence orders

Tags: relations, order-theory

As I understand it, transitivity is compulsory to all types of orders.

In addition when the relation is also irreflexive (and consequently anti-symmetric), then it is called **weak partial order**.
On the other hand, if the relation is reflexive, there can be two situations.

1. Either it's symmetric, in which case it is **preorder** (or equivalence relation).
2. Or it's anti-symmetric, in which case it is **strong partial order**.

I have three questions:

a. Is my above understanding correct?

b. Are *partial order*, *weak order* other terms for **weak partial order**?

c. Are *strict partial order*, *strict weak order* other terms for **strong partial order**?

EDIT: Citing different sources from where confusion arises.

- Partee, B. H., Meulen, A. G. B. ter, & Wall, R. E. (1990). Mathematical methods in linguistics. Kluwer Academic.

  - Pg. 47, *"An order is a binary relation which is transitive and in addition either (i) reflexive and antisymmetric or else (ii) irreflexive and asymmetric. The former are weak orders; the latter are strict (or strong)"*.
  - Pg. 208-209, authors state that a relation is a weak partial order iff it's transitive, reflexive and antisymmetric; it's strict partial iff transitive, irreflexive and asymmetric.
- Narens, L. (2015). Probabilistic Lattices: With Applications to Psychology (Vol. 5). World Scientific.

  - On Pg. 29 author states conditions for different orders.

    - partial ordering: reflexive, transitive, and antisymmetric
    - weak ordering: transitive and connected
    - total ordering: weak ordered and antisymmetric.
  - He also states that weak orderings are also partial orderings, so each concept in the list is a generalization of the next.
- Lehman, Eric, Leighton, F Thomson, & Meyer, Albert R (2018). Mathematics for Computer Science.

  - Pg. 448, "*R is a strict partial order iff R is transitive and irreflexive iff R is transitive and asymmetric." "R is a weak partial order iff R is transitive and anti-symmetric and reflexive."*

Comment: transitivity: [formal properties of *order* relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory#Background_and_motivation) are the way we capture the intuition about "ordering". "Some orders, like "less-than" on the natural numbers and alphabetical order on words, have a special property: each element can be compared to any other element, i.e. it is smaller (earlier) than, larger (later) than, or identical to. However, many other orders do not."

Comment: Not all Authors will use the Exact Same Definitions. You should include the Definitions that you are referring to here. That will enable getting "Correct Answers" without guesswork & inaccuracies.

Comment: From that, the first basic difference between [Partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Partial_order) and [Total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Orders, Partial Orders, Strict Partial Orders, Total Orders, Strict Total Orders, and Strict Orders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210560/orders-partial-orders-strict-partial-orders-total-orders-strict-total-orders)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA- Hey, thanks for pointing out that answer. The answer refers to certain points but not all of the ones I have raised.
I have made edits to clarify my questions.

Comment: @Prem Thanks for pointing out. I have added details.