# How is the order "less than" on Natural number a total order?

Tags: relations, order-theory

First of all, I'm confused between the terms Order and Relation; I know what a relation on a set means, but don't know exactly a what order is. I may have used these terms as if they almost mean the same.

In [wikipedia: order theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory), it says -

> Some orders, like "less-than" on the natural numbers and alphabetical order on words, have a special property: each element can be compared to any other element, i.e. it is smaller (earlier) than, larger (later) than, or **identical to**. However, many other orders do not. Consider for example the subset order on a collection of sets: though the set of birds and the set of dogs are both subsets of the set of animals, neither the birds nor the dogs constitutes a subset of the other. Those orders like the "subset-of" relation for which there exist incomparable elements are called partial orders; orders for which every pair of elements is comparable are total orders.

What I conclude from this text is that, if a relation can be applied between any two elements of set, then that relation is a total order.

In the first example, they said that in natural numbers, under the relation "less-than", every kind of pairs (not ordered, which means (1, 2) = (2, 1)) is **comparable**, does that mean that all these pairs fulfill the statement `e1 < e2`, where e1 and e2 are elements of the given pair? If yes, then how does identical element's pair fulfill this statement?

consider pairs: (1, 2), (4, 1), (5, 5)
1st and 2nd pairs fulfill the statement `e1 < e2`: 1 < 2 and 1 < 4, but 3rd pair doesn't as 5 < 5 is false.

So, How is the order "less than" on Natural number a total order?

Comment: You conclude wrong. Strict orders are total when they are trichotomic.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Do you mean that in case of natural number, order '<' is total because any pair of Natural numbers fulfills **exactly** one of these: a < b, a > b or a == b?

Comment: Yes, that is what I said.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Strict_and_non-strict_total_orders

Comment: @ArturoMagidin okay, but are we okay with including `equality` relation when we are studying the property of '<' relation on natural numbers? I thought it would be good to discuss about the properties of '<' by only using '<' relation, for example, we could discribe the relation '<' on a natural number as a total order becuase any pair (a, b) where ** a != b** fulfills exactly one of these: a < b or b < a. I know this definition could be totally different than what it is right now, but atleast we are only using '<' relation to  describe its properties in this way

Comment: @Cinverse In math and logic, the identity relation is a fundamental relation. So it is totally ok to use identity in definitions, just as you would be using ‘and’s and ‘or’s in definitions. Indeed, without identity it would be hard to get anything interesting off the ground.

Comment: @Cinverse Anyway, going back to your question: based on my own research and questions I have asked myself (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2210560/orders-partial-orders-strict-partial-orders-total-orders-strict-total-orders) there does not seem to be a simple mathematical definition of ‘order’. It seems that typically, when mathematicians use ‘order’ they mean ‘partial order’ … but since partial orders are reflexive, while strict orders are not, that would imply that strict orders are not ‘orders’. Very strange.

Comment: @Cinverse Now, the basic idea of a *total* order is one where for any two elements, one stands in that relation to the other or vice versa. As you say, any two elements should be ‘comparable’. Ok, so why then is < considered a total order when an element does not stay in that relation to itself? Doesn’t that violate the basic idea? Well, think of it as the exception. Indeed, best is to think of a total order as one where any two *different* elements are ‘comparable’

Comment: @cinverse So, something like < is a strict total order, while $\leq$ 
is a non-strict total order. But again we have some weirdness going on in that when mathematicians say ‘total order’, they typically mean a non-strict total order (e.g. Wilipedia page for total order) which would imply that a strict total order is not a ‘total order’. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

There really are two notions: *strict* partial order, and *non-strict* partial order. People usually prefer one to the other, and use "partial order" to refer to that, and use the additional adjective to refer to the remaining one.

Let $X$ be a set. A **non-strict partial order** on $X$ is a (binary) relation $\preceq$ on $X$ which is:

1. Reflexive: for all $x\in X$, $x\preceq x$;
2. Anti-symmetric: for all $x,y\in X$, if $x\preceq y$ and $y\preceq x$, then $x=y$.
3. Transitive: for all $x,y,z\in X$, if $x\preceq y$ and $y\preceq z$, then $x\preceq z$.

We say that the non-strictly partially ordered set $(X,\preceq)$ is **totally** ordered (or is "linearly non-strictly ordered") if and only if for all $x,y\in X$, either $x\preceq y$ or $y\preceq x$ (or both, in the case where $x=y$). This is sometimes called the "totality" property.

Now let $X$ be a set. A **strict partial order** on $X$ is a (binary) relation $\lt$ on $X$ which is:

1. Irreflexive: for all $x\in X$, $x\not\lt x$;
2. Transitive: for all $x,y,z\in X$, if $x\lt y$ and $y\lt z$, then $x\lt z$.

(Sometimes people also add "asymmetry": if $x\lt y$ then $y\not\lt x$; but note that this follows from 1 and 2: if $x\lt y$ and $y\lt x$, then transitivity would yield $x\lt x$, which contradicts irreflexivity).

A strictly partially ordered set $(X,\lt)$ is **totally** ordered if and only if it satisfies trichotomy:

> Trichotomy: for all $x,y\in X$, exactly one of the following three things happen:
>
> 1. $x=y$;
> 2. $x\lt y$;
> 3. $y\lt x$.

The two notions are equivalent in the following sense:

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be a set.
>
> 1. If $\preceq$ is a non-strict partial order on $X$, then define the binary relation $\lt$ on $X$ by $$x\lt y\iff x\preceq y\text{ and }x\neq y.$$
>    Then $(X,\lt)$ is a strictly partially ordered set. Moreover, $(X,\preceq)$ is a total order if and only if $(X,\lt)$ is a total order (that is, trichotomic).
> 2. If $\lt$ is a strict partial order on $X$, then define the binary relation $\preceq$ on $X$ by $$x\preceq y\iff x\lt y\text{ or }x=y.$$
>    Then $(X,\preceq)$ is a non-strict partially ordered set. Moreoever, $(X,\lt)$ is a total order (that is, trichotomic) if and only if $(X,\preceq)$ is a total order.

It is not hard to establish this theorem. It means, in spirit, that one can begin with either the concept of "non-strict partial order", and use it to make "strict partial order" a derived notion; or begin with the notion of "strict partial order" as your initial concept, and make non-strict partial orders a derived notion.

Historically, number theorists and those that start with the Natural numbers beginning at $1$, took strict partial orders to be the "initial" or "more primitive" notion of order, as the order on $\mathbb{N}$ was defined by $$a\lt b\iff \exists x\in\mathbb{N}\text{ such that }a+x=b.$$
Which is the "strictly less than" notion of the usual order of $\mathbb{N}$. By contrast, those who began with set theory (and defined $\mathbb{N}$ using von Neumann ordinals so that they began at zero) considered non-strict partial orders (the canonical example of which is the subset relation, $A\subseteq B$) to be the more "primitive" notion, with strict orders being defined in terms of the partial orders instead.

That means that when someone says "partially ordered set", you kind of need to know whether they mean "non-strict" or "strict" partial order. This is usually understood from context or from choice of symbols ($\leq$ vs. $\lt$; $\subseteq$ vs. $\subset$, etc). Then "total order" will mean either that for every $x$ and $y$ you have either $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x$, or both; or else that for all $x$ and $y$, you have exactly one of $x\lt y$, $y\lt x$, or $x=y$ (if you are working with strict orders).

Whichever notion you are using (strict order or non-strict order), the Natural numbers with their usual ordering are totally ordered, since they satisfy either totality (for non-strict order); or trichotomy (for strict order).